# How many pairs of Interior angles In a ratio $3:2$

Tags: geometry, fractions

> The ratio of the interior angles of two regular polygons is $3:2$. How many such pairs are there?

My original idea was to incorporate elementary modular arithmetic so either eliminate or zone in particular pairs.

Just as a background, there is no calculus required (as the book has not talked about) no too complex math (the highest level maths is probably Algebra 2, 11th grade).

Also, I'm not out here looking for a solution but hint or idea to help me, so please do not give a full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number of sides of the polygons be $n$ and $k$. We have:

$$\frac{180(n-2)/n}{180(k-2)/k} = \frac{3}{2}$$
$$2(180 \cdot\frac{n-2}{n}) = 3(180\cdot\frac{k-2}{k})$$
$$\frac{2n-4}{n} = \frac{3k-6}{k}$$
$$2nk-4k = 3nk-6n$$
$$nk + 4k - 6n = 0$$

Now if we subtract $24$ from both sides:

$$nk + 4k -6n - 24 = -24$$
$$(n+4)(k-6) = -24$$

Can you continue?

Comment: yes thanks, just a simple diophantine equation

Comment: Now you can use the factors of $24$ to help. Don't forget about the negative cases such as $k-6=1$, $k-6=-1$ (if the numbers make sense).

Comment: yes, i understand thank you :)

Comment: oh wait, you used Simon's favorite factoring trick lol

Comment: Didn't know this had a name! But yes, that's what I used.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the polygons have $m$ and $n$ sides respectively.

The interior angle of a regular $x$-gon is $180 - \frac{360}{x}$

Hence

$\frac{180 - \frac{360}{m}}{180 - \frac{360}{m}} = \frac{3}{2}$

Simplifying,

$6m - 4n = mn$

The above equation has $4$ solutions:

$(2, 2), (4, 3), (8, 4), (20, 5)$

In this case, we discard the solution $(2,2)$

Hence the final solutions are $(4, 3), (8, 4), (20, 5)$

Comment: thank you for the help!!

Comment: Note that $(2,2)$ does not make sense, so you can discard it.

Comment: Thanks... Fixed!